# which has less time and space complexity when we have to perform stack operations like push and pull?

Tags: function, stack, push

which has less time and space complexity when we have to perform stack operations like push and pull?
a) When we include library of stack
b) When we define functions of push and pop

When you define your own functions for push and pop operations, you have control over the implementation. If you design your functions efficiently, you can ensure that the time complexity is also constant or at least very low for these operations.

Answer (score 0):

If the maximum possible size is known, then an array can be used similar to an actual stack with a single index (or pointer). You can start from the top of the array and use pre-decrement of an index (or pointer) for push, and post-increment for pop. This has the advantage that a peek operation uses the index (or pointer) as is.